# How to merge multiple pictures diagonally into a single one using Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to merge multiple images diagonally into a single one using Python. 
I checked a lot of questions but didn't find something similar to my need.

All I can do right now is a simple merge of files on top of each other:

```
from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

img = Image.open("1.png")

background = Image.open("2.png")

background.paste(img, (0, 0), img)

background.save('result.png',"PNG")
```

Here are the pictures to test :

[image1](https://i.ibb.co/fd1FbnN/1.png), [image2](https://i.ibb.co/PhTSvJr/2.png), [image3](https://i.ibb.co/ZgmTcnq/3.png)

I need the pictures to be arranged diagonally to fit into a final **900 x 1200** px size picture with white Background. Probably they need to be sized down a bit and fit ? At least that's the process I am doing in Photoshop, manually (time consuming).

Sometimes there's 2 pictures to fit, sometimes could be 4 or 5.

[image: Final desired result]

Comment: The white background will overlay in your resulting image. You should use svg  images with a transparent background instead.

Comment: Interesting...so do I have to convert the png's(transparent) to svg ? that's what you're trying to say ?

Comment: I say the first step would be to make the background transparent before overlaying them, otherwise, you will just end up with a picture of the front sweater and a lot of white borders.

Comment: Sorry but why ? My files are already transparent png's . For me the hardest part is to figure out how to arrange them like in the final picture.

Comment: My bad then, thought the background was white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
from PIL import Image

images = ['1.png', '2.png', '3.png']

# shift between images
offset = (200, 100)
target_size = (900, 1200)

images = [Image.open(fn) for fn in images]
no_img = len(images)
image_size = [s+no_img*o for s, o in zip(images[0].size, offset)]

#create empty background
combined_image = Image.new('RGBA', image_size)

# paste each image at a slightly shifted position, start at top right
for idx, image in enumerate(images):
  combined_image.paste(image, ((no_img - idx - 1) * offset[0], idx * offset[1]), image)

# crop to non-empty area
combined_image = combined_image.crop(combined_image.getbbox())

# resizing and padding such that it fits 900 x 1200 px
scale = min(target_size[0] / combined_image.size[0], target_size[1] / combined_image.size[1])
combined_image = combined_image.resize((int(combined_image.size[0] * scale), int(combined_image.size[1] * scale)), Image.BICUBIC)
img_w, img_h = combined_image.size

finale_output = Image.new('RGB', target_size, (255, 255, 255))

offset = ((target_size[0] - img_w) // 2, (target_size[1] - img_h) // 2)
finale_output.paste(combined_image, offset, combined_image)

# display
finale_output.show()
```

EDIT: I added the code for resizing and padding such that the output is exactly of your wanted size (whilst maintaining the aspect ratio).

Comment: fantastic !!! I was about to ask you about that, 'cause I tried using 4 images and the final file got bigger than 900x1200 ! You are my hero !

Comment: I noticed after you updated your answer, the final result became super sharp :( do you know what it could be ?

Comment: also, do you know if it's possible to save the file as psd with layers ? is python capable of doing something like this ?

Comment: Retry, I added bicubic interpolation, default is nearest-neighbour. There are some libraries supporting PSD (I just googled it), but I don't have any experience there. Consider using TIFF, it supports layers as well.

Comment: Found a small error in your code on line 25 PIL.Image.BICUBIC - removed the PIL. - worked fine ! Thank you again !

Comment: Yes, I had an additional import. I fixed it. Thx.